# Get image url through User Model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a rule inside the user model, to check the user image is exist, and if it is exist return back the complete image url, I am doing this way but not working in foreach($users as $user) loop.

```
    public function Image(){
    $image = $this->user->image;
    if(empty($image)){
    $image = asset('images/profile/no-image.png');
    }else{
    $image = asset('images/profile/no-image.png');
    }
    return $image;
    }
```

Comment: What is your foreach syntax?

Comment: I am getting the users through Friend model that is connected to user model by: return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'requester_id'); and in my blade view I am using this:  <img src="{{$user->user->Image}}"> inside foreach loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put the function on friend model then move it to your user model. Then make the function like this:

```
public function Image()
{
    if ($this->image) {
        return asset('images/profile/' . $this->image);
    } else {
        return asset('images/profile/no-image.png');
    }
}
```

But i suggest you to use [laravel Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators):

```
public function getImageAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value) {
        return asset('images/profile/' . $value);
    } else {
        return asset('images/profile/no-image.png');
    }
}
```

Then you can get image attribute through your model:

```
foreach($friends as $friend) {
    {{ $friend->user->image }}
}
```

Comment: I got the second option which is using Accessor and it is working thanks, but I did not understand the first option, what you mean by if you put the function on friend model then move it to your user model.

Comment: You coded like $this->user->image, so i thought maybe you put function in friends class. By the way, if you use accessor then you can't check $user->image any more elsewhere. Because user model always return accessor return value instead of regular model value.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is store a default image in the database when te user is created. This is my migration. The table avatar has a default value `default.png`

```
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('avatar')->default('default.png');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

To get the image you simply call it like this

```
<img src="/image/location/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}">
```

In a foreach loop you do something like this:

```
$users = User::all();
avatars = [];
foreach ($users as $key => $user){
    $avatars[] = $user->avatar;
}
```

This returns an array of you avatars or in blade you do something like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<img src="/image/location/{{ $user->avatar }}">
@endforeach
```